# How Do I Get The Current CSS3 Filter Property Function Argument Values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, css

If I use `$('#my-div').css("-webkit-filter")` (jQuery) on a DOM object with a CSS3 filter property applied, the following string is returned:

```
 "blur(*px) invert(100%) etc"
```

How can I quickly find out the current value of each individual CSS3 filter property function argument (and perhaps also transform property) applied to a given DOM element?

Comment: Take that string and use `.split(" ")`? Then you can investigate `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. I know nothing about the `-webkit-filter` property, so I'm not sure if that really helps :)

Comment: I was thinking along those lines (a regex possibly), but I suspect there must be a cleaner way to do it, because it's the type of thing that you'd want to do at some point, IMO.

Comment: Ahh yes, a regex would make more sense, now that I see the details of the property. Well, I thought maybe there would be "sub" properties...kind of like how `border` is technically made up of `border-style`, `border-width`, `border-color`, etc....but I can't seem to find any details like that for `filter`. A regex might not be a bad idea though. Could be a fun little project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `.css`, which wraps `window.getComputedStyle`, does a nice job of normalizing the CSS values.  A general regex to capture the name/value is

```
/(?:^|\s+)(.*?)\((.*?)\)/g
```

You can use `.replace` without replacing in order to acquire the name of the filter and its value separately, perhaps storing them in an object.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/26kNc/

Comment: In the absence of a sensible getter method of some sort, this looks pretty good. Thanks.